# Can I configure my .bashrc to highlight the fact that I'm in a Prod directory?

Tags: shell, colors, prompt

Currently, I'm using the following:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=6
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\ 
[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
```

I have little clue on how this actually works! It does trim my directory to make it more readable, and adds some color.

---

[image]

---

Is there a way that I can modify my options here to make it super clear that I'm in a production directory? I'm thinking something like if my current `pwd` contains `prod` or `production`, then my prompt changes colors drastically (like annoyingly bright red, or some other obvious change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` setting, which allows you to run arbitrary code prior to printing the prompt. (Assumes bash.) As proof of concept:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='case "$PWD" in *prod*) printf "\033[31m%s/\033[0m > " ${PWD##*/} ;; *) printf "%s/ > " ${PWD##*/};; esac'
```

Which uses an xterm escape code to set the foreground color to red if the `PWD` variable contains "prod" anywhere, but only displays the top most directory name in the prompt. Advanced color code discussion here: https://superuser.com/questions/270214/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-my-xterm-using-ansi-escape-sequences

Comment: This kind of works, but it doesn't do what I'm looking for exactly (I'd rather not add more text to my prompt).

Comment: It's not set in stone. Modify it to your taste. PROMPT_COMMAND can be a simple or complex action.